# How can I sort my HTTP GET to return what I need?

Tags: python, http, get, request

So I'm making an HTTP GET request for a query which returns me some data.

The answer I'm getting is exactly what I want/what I expected. Now I'm wondering how I can take only what I want from the returned data.

This is the code I'm running:

```
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS, auth = AUTH)
print (r.text)
```

And this is what I get from it:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[{"metric":{},"values":[[1567169541,"1"],[1567169556,"1"],[1567169571,"1"],[1567169586,"1"],[1567169601,"1"]]}]}}
```

What I need from this is only the number inside the "values". So there's a whole lot of data I don't need. Inside the brackets there's also a timestamp which I don't need.

I really ony need the number.

So how can I do this?

Comment: How did you get that? `r` itself *contains* the response, but depending on which attribute or method of `r` you are using, you have either a `dict` or a JSON value that needs to be decoded to a `dict`.

Comment: I'm adding that code right now. It's just displayed with a text print so a dict I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.text` is the literal body of the response; in this case, it contains a JSON value that needs to be decoded to get a `dict`:

```
d = json.decodes(r.text)
```

However, the `Response` object has a method to do that for you.

```
d = r.json()
```

Now it's just a matter of indexing the Python data structure appropriately.

```
# d['data']['result'] == [{"metric":{},"values":[[1567169541,"1"],[1567169556,"1"],[1567169571,"1"],[1567169586,"1"],[1567169601,"1"]]}]
# x only takes a single value in this case, as the above is a singleton list
# y == [1567169541,"1"]
#      [1567169556,"1"]
#      etc
values = [y[0] for x in d['data']['result'] for y in x['values']]
```